# Submit checkbox values to Controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am having the following form, which I would like to submit to my backend.

```html
<form id="revisionFilter" action="{{ route('revision.filter') }}" method='POST'>
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="checkbox1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox1">
                                    1
                                </label>
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="checkbox0">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox0">
                                    0
                                </label>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="checkboxNull">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1">
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="checkboxNull">
                                    Null
                                </label>
  <input type="hidden" name='_method' value='POST'>
  <input id="revisionFilterSubmit" type="submit" class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' value='Filter'>
</form>
```

My backend looks like the following:

**routes:**

```
Route::post('/revision/filter', 'RevisionController@filter')->name('revision.filter');
```

**RevisionController:**

```
public function filter(Request $request)
{
    Log::info("Request: ");
    Log::info($request);

    return redirect()->route('revision.rindex');
}
```

My problem is that when I press the button I am getting redirected to:

```
The page has expired due to inactivity. 

Please refresh and try again.
```

Instead I would like to see the request with the values of the checkboxes to implement the db saving functionality.

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: add a CSRF field in your form using `{{ csrf_field() }}`

Comment: @Wreigh Thx for your answer! The request I get looks the following: `array (
  '_token' => '0l3rUUfpQGxnOX9Jpim9vEXQEkCFP7nqsQiSfhwh',
  '_method' => 'POST',
)  
` Any suggestions how to get the checkbox values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since I've already made a comment. I will put my answer in the answer box lol.

To answer you, you're not getting any checkbox value since you're checkboxes don't have any `name` attribute.

You need to put a `name` attribute to them. E.g.,

`<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" name="checkbox0" id="checkbox0">`

From there, you should now be able to see the value of the checkbox via its name.

Answer (score 0):

Just put same name to your checkbox.For example

```
 <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="checkbox1" name="revisionFilter">
 <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="checkbox2" name="revisionFilter">
```